# How can I target a column of data from a csv?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

Goal: Find the average of the 'budget' column (data from an imported csv file).

So far I have gotten my program to open and print the contents of the spreadsheet and have cleaned up the formatting some.

I'm not sure how to attach the file to this post, but the columns read ['title,year,length,budget,rating,votes\r\n']

How can I begin to manipulate the data? More specifically target the 'budget' column and begin doing the math.

PS: I have been asked to figure this out without using the 'import csv' module.

My work so far:

```
f = open("movies.csv") 
lines = f.readlines()

i = 0

while i < len(lines):
    line = lines[i]
    line = line[:-2] # remove trailine \r\n\ from line
    print "%4d   %s" % (i+1, line)
    i = i + 1
```

Comment: Then, use numpy module. Convert your list of lists into numpy array after the 'while' cycle. And apply slicing.

Comment: if you ever need to do these things outside of assignments, you should check out [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) if you haven't - it has cool functions such as [read_csv()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

Answer (score 2):

Use `csv` module from standard library https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

```
import csv
with open('movies.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    budgets = [row['budget'] for row in reader]
```

And now you can manipulate it in any way you want, all of your budgets are in `budgets` variable

Answer (score 0):

You can split your csv file like this to get only the required column. Here I am printing a price column from .csv file.

```
 >>> for line in open("SalesJan2009.csv"):
...     csv_row = line.split('\r')[0].split(',')
...     print csv_row[2]
```

the output is as follows. you can sum them instead of printing

```
Price
1200
1200
1200
1200
3600
1200
1200
1200
1200
1200
1200
1200
1200
1200
1200
1200
1200
1200
3600
```

Comment: Running into some trouble with this: Some movies in this spreadsheet don't have a listed budget and are marked with 'NA' (not applicable) in the spreadsheet. This is creating issues. [link]http://imgur.com/a/0tVQO

Comment: If you are summing all the budget values do this : `if csv_row[2] != 'NA': sum+=int(csv_row[2])`

Answer (score 0):

```
f=open('movies.csv','r')
lines = f.read().split('\n')   #create list from the lines read
header_list = lines[0].strip().split(',') # first item of the list is header line make it a list , so that you can get the index of your keyword budget
index = header_list.index('budget')

total_budget = 0
count = 0

for item in lines[1:]:  # skip the first line which is a header
    if item != '':
        if item.strip().split(',')[index] is not 'NA':
            total_budget += float(item.strip().split(',')[index])
            count +=1

print  total_budget
avg_budget = total_budget/count
print avg_budget
```

Comment: this is the solution considering no importing inbuilt modules

Comment: Error: "could not convert string to float: NA" In this column there are 'Not Applicable - NA' lines. How can I skip these and proceed to the next line with a conditional statement?

Comment: HI Xavier, please check I have added an extra condition to check NA.